# facebook insight (page-insights) HTTP status code: 200

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-insights

using this code but showing "HTTP status 200" I checked Facebook documentation but issue didn't resolve kindly help me out there

```
$requestPageInsights = $fb->request('GET', '/Page-ID/insights/post_storytellers?, $accessToken');
```

//Make a batch request

```
$batch = ['page-insights' => $requestPageInsights];

try {
 $responses = $fb->sendBatchRequest($batch);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
```

// When Graph returns an error

```
 echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
 exit;
 } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
```

// When validation fails or other local issues

```
echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
}


foreach ($responses as $key => $response) {
if ($response->isError()) {
 $e = $response->getThrownException();
 echo '<p>Error! Facebook SDK Said: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n\n";
 echo '<p>Graph Said: ' . "\n\n";
 var_dump($e->getResponse());
 } else {
  echo "<p>(" . $key . ") HTTP status code: " . $response->getHttpStatusCode() . "<br />\n";
   echo "Response: " . $response->getBody() . "</p>\n\n";
   echo "<hr />\n\n";
  }
}
```

and Output is:
(page-insights) HTTP status code: 200
Response: {"data":[],"paging":{"previous":"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/1**********1/insights?

I think its a paging issue, but don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: Why are you trying to make a batch request here? And the result looks like you simply don’t have the necessary permission to read the insights for that page.

Comment: Yes I noted that I don't have permissions, and got solution btw why not I make a batch request?

Comment: A batch request would only make sense if you have several individual requests that you want to “group” into one ... from your example it was not clear if that’s the case, or if you really only wanted insights for one single page.

Comment: Yes I need it so right now I am just testing it.